# I can't get my images in css to change their size to 50px do you know any reason that could be?

Tags: css

```
.image{/*gotta fix. my boarder is
  changing but not the image*/ 
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
 
  width: 20%;
  height:auto;
  object-fit: fill;
```

I've tried style element inline and <style ></style> but neither Methode seem to work. my css code works but not for this line of code for some reason.

Comment: i meant to put 5% not pixels in the question, but i did try px as well but my webpage just makes the images bunch up together. I'm still trying methods to see what works.

Comment: do you want to put all your images in one "div" and then put "display:flex"?

Comment: checkout this link : https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_image_gallery

Comment: i put the class in multiply div elements to keep them from positioning the price number below each image.

Comment: I think it's better to upload as much of your code as possible. when you edit your question, there is a " >< " tab on the top row. Press that and insert your HTML and CSS code in its related sections.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why your images might not be changing their size to 50px in CSS could be that there is another CSS rule that is overriding the one you have written for sizing the images. You can try using the !important declaration after your CSS rule for the image size to ensure it takes precedence over any other rules that might be affecting it.For example, if you have written:

```
img {
  width: 50px;
}

You can change it to:
img {
  width: 50px !important;
}
```

Another reason could be that the selector you are using in your CSS rule is not targeting the specific images you want to resize. You can check the class or id of the image element and make sure it matches the selector in your CSS code.

Comment: i'll look and see if I have a css rule some were else.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. So I just deleted two of the div elements leaving one wrapped around all the images and p tag prices, so now the code works thank you guys for helping me.